# UWP text to speech from listbox (c#')

Tags: c#, listbox, win-universal-app, text-to-speech

I am trying to implement text to speech to read items from a listbox in order. Initially the program would read out all items at the same time overlapping each other. After researching I added a MediaEnded handler but I can only manage to read out the first item only with this implemented. I would appreciate any help.

```
    private async void ToSpeechButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            MediaElement mediaElement = new MediaElement();
            var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            mediaElement.MediaEnded += (o, f) => { tsc.TrySetResult(true); };
            mediaElement.Play();

        foreach (var item in ListBox.Items)
        {   
            readText(item.ToString());
            await tsc.Task;
        }                

    }


    private async void readText(string mytext)
    {
        MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
        using (var speech = new SpeechSynthesizer())
        {
            speech.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(gender => gender.Gender == VoiceGender.Female);
            SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await speech.SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync(mytext);
            mediaplayer.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
            mediaplayer.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you just Combine all the Items together as one string and pass this string to `readText(string mytext)` method?

Comment: Thanks, I have done this but the problem with this is that the speech will read every listbox element immediately without any pause inbetween elements. Do know how I could pause it if I put all elements in one string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the document of [SpeechSynthesizer class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer.aspx), you will find there are two method to convert text to speech. One is what you have used, [SynthesizeTextToStreamAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer.synthesizetexttostreamasync.aspx), this method asynchronously generate speech output from a string.

The other one is [SynthesizeSsmlToStreamAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer.synthesizessmltostreamasync.aspx), and this method asynchronously generate speech output from a string containing [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis/).

In this case, we can use `SynthesizeSsmlToStreamAsync` method to pause the speech between each item for example like this:

```
private string allitem;

private void ToSpeechButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in listBox.Items)
    {
        var txt = item as ListBoxItem;
        allitem += txt.Content.ToString() + "<break time='500ms'/>";
    }
    readText(allitem);
}

private async void readText(string mytext)
{
    MediaElement mediaplayer = new MediaElement();
    using (var speech = new SpeechSynthesizer())
    {
        speech.Voice = SpeechSynthesizer.AllVoices.First(gender => gender.Gender == VoiceGender.Female);
        string ssml = @"<speak version='1.0' " + "xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'>" + allitem + "</speak>";
        SpeechSynthesisStream stream = await speech.SynthesizeSsmlToStreamAsync(ssml);
        mediaplayer.SetSource(stream, stream.ContentType);
        mediaplayer.Play();
    }
}
```

Combine this `<break time='500ms'/>` string after each item, the speech will pause for 500ms after each item.

Comment: Thanks Grace, do you know if it would be possible to have the speech synthesis read out only one list element at a time when they click the button? For example on the first click it would read listbox element 1 and on second click it would read listbox element 2. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property of the `ListBox`.

Comment: Hi, nice piece of code but what about change the lenguaje ? I need spanish (Colombia) is it possible?

Comment: @JuanPabloGomez, The tts voice is controlled by a default voice package that comes with Windows. To change it you'll have to go in Control Panel -> Speech Recognition -> Text to Speech. There you can select your prefered Voice.